# Dropdown Selected item working in DropDownList but not in DropDownListFor - MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am not able to identify why DropDownListFor is not selecting the correct option. Below is my code, I have hard-coded 'Selected' values for testing but still when page loads I am getting 'Select Country' as selected value.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CountryID, 
                        new List<SelectListItem> { 
                                new SelectListItem { Text = "USA", Value = "US", Selected =  false},
                                new SelectListItem { Text = "UK", Value = "UK", Selected =  true},
                                new SelectListItem { Text = "Australia", Value = "AUS", Selected = false }
                        },"Select Country")
```

But, same is working fine for DropDownList!

```
@Html.DropDownList("CountryID", 
                        new List<SelectListItem> { 
                                new SelectListItem { Text = "USA", Value = "US", Selected =  false},
                                new SelectListItem { Text = "UK", Value = "UK", Selected =  true},
                                new SelectListItem { Text = "Australia", Value = "AUS", Selected = false }
                        },"Select Country")
```

Please Help.

Comment: You should set the value of Model.CountryID to the item you want to be selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selected option will be based on the actual value of property `CountryID` when you use the strongly type helper. So if you set `CountryID="UK"` in the controller before you pass the model to the view, then the second option will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
@{
   var listItems = new List<SelectListItem>
   {
      new SelectListItem { Text = "USA", Value = "USA" },
      new SelectListItem { Text = "UK", Value = "UK", Selected = true },
      new SelectListItem { Text = "Australia", Value = "AUS" }
   };       
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CountryID, listItems, "-- Select Country --")
```